# Receiving 405 Method Not Allowed when using Rest Template

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to consume a 3rd party public api but getting a 405 error when trying to consume direct from a RestTemplate.

Initially I tried to consume the api direct from my angular application but discovered that CORS got in the way. Also doing it this way I can do any extra processing.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v2/laundry", produces = "application/json")
public class LaundryController {

  @GetMapping("/service_accounts")
  @ApiOperation(value = "Get all accounts for a given service provider")
  public String getServiceAccounts(@RequestParam(name="service", defaultValue = "") String service) throws PermissionException {
    Authorization.isAdmin();
    final String uri = "https://flashcashservice.gi-web.net/api/washstation/accounts";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
    return result;
  }
}
```

At the moment I am just looking to get the returned string. Currently receiving the following from Gradle.

```
2019-11-01 10:04:59.449 DEBUG 20716 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/v2/laundry/service_account?service=WASHSTATION", parameters={masked}
2019-11-01 10:04:59.459 DEBUG 20716 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Using @ExceptionHandler public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
2019-11-01 10:04:59.459  WARN 20716 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported
2019-11-01 10:04:59.462 DEBUG 20716 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : No match for [application/json, text/plain, */*], supported: []
2019-11-01 10:04:59.462  WARN 20716 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
2019-11-01 10:04:59.462 DEBUG 20716 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
```

Comment: `GET not supported`

Comment: Could you use @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET}, value = "/service_accounts") and let us know the output.

Comment: @amy Yep still getting the same response.

Comment: Please provide full implementation of java class as well as the ajax or similar call implementation from client if exist

Comment: @amy thanks for getting me to double check my front-end I had a typo in my service call.